# Check if element is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make an if statement to work so that when a user clicks a heading it checks to see if its open if it is hide the body else nothing.

```
if ($(".faq-body",this).is(':visible')) {
    $(".faq-item").click(function() {
        $(".faq-body",this).hide();
    });
} else {
        //something later
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling your click handler and if statement are backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your if statement in the wrong place, it should be inside the click event like this:

```
// Adding this line to make sure we're binding this to $(document).ready()
$(function(){
  $(".faq-item").click(function(){
    if ($(".faq-body",this).is(':visible')) {
      $(".faq-body",this).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

This is assuming `.faq-body` is inside of `.faq-item`

In your version, it's checking the condition immediately on page load and only binding the event if it succeeds that one time.